# Vue i18n - Locale changed but the text is not requesting the translated text from locales assets

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-i18n

I am using VueI18n for support of two languages in a website, build on VueJS, but now I want to switch between the two languages. I can change the locale that set the languages with i18n but it won't get the translated text without refresh, I want it to be seamless.

[Before Translating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ph2K6.png)

[After Translating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZWAM.png)

My Code for the translate button

```
<v-btn
                  elevation="0"
                  outlined
                  class="px-0 rounded-lg"
                  color="primary"
                  @click.native.stop="$i18n.locale = 'en'"
                  v-if="$i18n.locale === 'id'"
                >
                  <country-flag
                    class="ma-0"
                    :country="$i18n.locale == 'en' ? 'us' : $i18n.locale"
                  />
                  <h4 class="text-uppercase font-weight black--text mr-3">
                    {{ $i18n.locale == "en" ? "en" : "id" }}
                  </h4>
                </v-btn>
                <v-btn
                  elevation="0"
                  outlined
                  class="px-0 rounded-lg"
                  color="primary"
                  @click.native.stop="$i18n.locale = 'id'"
                  v-else
                >
                  <country-flag
                    class="ma-0"
                    :country="$i18n.locale == 'en' ? 'us' : $i18n.locale"
                  />
                  <h4 class="text-uppercase font-weight black--text mr-3">
                    {{ $i18n.locale == "en" ? "en" : "id" }}
                  </h4>
                </v-btn>
```

Any answer will be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a component like this:

```html
<template>
  <v-menu offset-y top nudge-top="4" transition="scale-transition" origin="bottom left">
    <template #activator="{on}">
      <v-btn text height="30" class="px-2" v-on="on">
        <v-avatar size="20">
          <img :src="currentFlag">
        </v-avatar>
        <span class="text-uppercase ml-2">{{ currentLocale }}</span>
      </v-btn>
    </template>
    <v-list dense class="py-0">
      <v-list-item v-for="locale in locales" :key="locale" class="pl-2" @click="changeLocale(locale)">
        <v-list-item-icon class="my-0 mr-1 align-self-center">
          <v-icon v-if="locale === currentLocale">mdi-check-bold</v-icon>
        </v-list-item-icon>
        <v-list-item-avatar size="20" class="my-0">
          <img :src="allFlags[locale]">
        </v-list-item-avatar>
        <v-list-item-title class="pl-2">{{ $root.$i18n.messages[locale].locale }}</v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item>
    </v-list>
  </v-menu>
</template>

<script>
export default
{
  name: 'LanguageSwitcher',
  computed:
    {
      locales()
      {
        return Object.keys(this.$root.$i18n.messages);
      },
      currentLocale()
      {
        return this.$root.$i18n.locale;
      },
      allFlags()
      {
        return Object.fromEntries(this.locales.map(locale => [locale, process.env.BASE_URL + 'flags/' + locale + '.png']));
      },
      currentFlag()
      {
        return process.env.BASE_URL + 'flags/' + this.currentLocale + '.png';
      },
    },
  methods:
  {
    changeLocale(locale)
    {
      const exist = locale in this.$i18n.messages;
      if (exist)
      {
        this.$i18n.locale = locale;
        this.$vuetify.lang.current = locale;
        document.querySelector('html').setAttribute('lang', locale);

        // update page title
        this.updateDocTitle(this.$route, this.$i18n);

        // update user preferences - only if logged-in
        if (this[GET_TOKEN])
        {
          this.$axios.post('/setLanguage', {
            lang: locale
          });
        }
        this[SET_LOCALE](locale);

        // now reset the validation of all forms - otherwise the validation errors remain in the old locale
        const child = this.$children.slice();
        let cur;
        while (child.length > 0)
        {
          cur = child.shift();
          if (cur.$options.name === 'v-form') cur.resetValidation();
          else
          {
            cur = cur.$children.slice();
            for (let i = 0; i < cur.length; i++) child.push(cur[i]);
          }
        }
      }
    },
    updateDocTitle(route, localizerInstance)
    {
      let title = typeof route.meta.title === 'function' ? route.meta.title(route) : route.meta.title; // must be a localization string identifier
      if (title)
      {
        // we need this workaround with ".apply()" because VueI18n.prototype.t() uses/requires valid (non-empty) THIS
        title = localizerInstance.t.apply(localizerInstance, ['pages.' + title]); // eslint-disable-line no-useless-call
        document.title = title;
      }
      else document.title = 'My Custom Project';
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

and keep in mind that you should change the root locale (`this.$root.$i18n.local`) rather than the component's local locale (`this.$i18n.locale`) because otherwise the change won't be global to the whole application but local only to the given component.

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix for why that mine is not work, that @click in there only change the locales and not not loading the json assets from locales so this is the fix for it.

```
            <v-btn
              elevation="0"
              outlined
              class="px-0 rounded-lg"
              color="primary"
              @click="changeLocale('id')" 
              v-else
            >
              <country-flag
                class="ma-0"
                :country="$i18n.locale == 'en' ? 'us' : $i18n.locale"
              />
              <h4 class="text-uppercase font-weight black--text mr-3">
                {{ $i18n.locale == "en" ? "en" : "id" }}
              </h4>
            </v-btn>
```

and this methods here is needed for it to be worked

```
methods: {
changeLocale(code) {
  this.$i18n.setLocale(code);
},
```